# PHP OOP query is not executing

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am using PHP with OOP to select rows from the database (MySQL).

When I execute the query, it returns an empty row.

Here is the classe I am using:

```
<?php 
class EmploiManager
{
 private $_db; 

 public function __construct($db)
 {
   $this->setDb($db);
 }
 public function category($category)
 {
   $q = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT * FROM DemandeEmploi WHERE category = :category');
   $q->execute(array('category' =>$category));
   $donnees = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   return new Emploi($donnees);
 }

 public function setDb(PDO $db)
 {
  $this->_db = $db;
 }
} 

$type = $_GET['category'];
$manager = new EmploiManager($db);
$row = $manager->category($type);

foreach ($row as $demandeE) 
{
  ?> 
    <div class="list"><h4><a href="?id=<? echo $demandeE->id();?>&category=demandemploi"><? echo $demandeE->title();?></a></h4> </div>      
    <?php
       } 
   ?>
```

Can any one tell me what's wrong with that code? 
Thanks!

Comment: Why not do error handling with `try/catch` block?

Comment: I tried It always shows nothing, but when I use `query()` instead of `prepare()` it gives this error: `Warning: PDO::query(): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'demploi' in 'where clause' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/gratisannonces.com/system/class/EmploiManager.class.php on line 28` . But the `demploi` it exists in the database in the column: `category`

Comment: You are saying `demoloi` your script says `demploi` and your code shows `DemandeEmploi` those are three different tables. Check it, because that is where your problem relies

Comment: yes yes I know :D , if you notice I changed `demoloi` into `demploi` it was an error of typing.

`demploi` it is not the name of the table, it's a value in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my bad, I didn't use a loop to select all the rows.

I corrected the code and it works fine now, here is what it looks like:

```
public function category($category)
{
  $datas = array();

  $q = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT * FROM DemandeEmploi WHERE category = :category');
  $q->execute(array('category' =>$category));

  while ($donnees = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
  {
    $datas[] = new Emploi($donnees);
  }
  return $datas;

}
```

Comment: If your solution works for you, than you should accept the answer.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm new here ^^
It says I can accept it tomorrow, so I will do then.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`$q->fetch()` just returns one row of the results. If you want all the results, you must use `$q->fetchAll()`.

Since you specified `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, the elements of `$row` will be associative arrays, not objects; aren't you getting errors saying that you're trying to call a method on a non-object? So `$demandeE->id()` should be `$demandeE['id']`, and `$demandeE->title()` should be `$demandeE['title']`.

Alternatively, you could specify `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`. Then, the values will be properties, not methods, so it should be `$demandeE->id` and `$demandeE->title` (no parentheses).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
No I'm not getting any error saying that i'm trying to call a method on a non-object, because I'm not getting the id and the title directly from the database, I am  getting them form the class Emploi that defines the setters and the getters and the columns that exists in the database: id, category, title...
I tired changing `fetch()` by `fetchAll()` but still the same problem.